# what joint should I use to pull an object?

Tags: box2d

Imagine I have this blue object (box2d body), which I need to draw towards the red "x" by its front end. While being pulled, the blue object has to collide with other objects in its path.

What kind of joint do you think I should use to pull this object?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you expect the user to pull the object manually using their mouse or finger? If so then you'll likely want [`b2MouseJoint`](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974) (section 10)

If another body will pull it under gravity (or an applied force), then you probably want [`b2DistanceJoint`](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974) (section 5)

Comment: no, the user won't be pulling the object. the idea is that the object should look as if crawling to the target by itself. It would be a top view, therefor with no gravity. I guess I could make the target also a body, connect them with a distanceJoint and then apply force to the target, so it would be pulling my object.

Comment: Yea, that sounds like a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a rope joint, and change the length of the rope over time. I don't think it would look right though, because a rope joint only constrains the body to a maximum distance, it doesn't impart any velocity to the body like a real rope pulling does.

You could also just apply a force towards the X without any joints at all, might work better.

Comment: Can I apply force to the object, so that it would be dragged to the target ( rather then just downwards ) by its front end ( not by center of mass ) ?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter to ApplyForce is the location at which to apply the force. http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces